# Missing control icons in Totem (Gnome Videos)

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, icons

I just did an update in Arch Linux, and now the Videos app (Totem) is using the same icon for every control:

[image: Totem screenshot]

The controls still work; you just can't tell them apart without hovering over the control until the tooltip shows up.  This worked fine before the upgrade.

I've reinstalled `totem`, `gnome-icon-theme`, `gnome-icon-theme-extras`, `gnome-icon-theme-symbolic`, and `hicolor-icon-theme`, but that made no difference.

Arch is currently on Gnome 3.6.  I'm using `x86_64`.

How do I get the controls labelled with the right icons?

**Update:** When I start `totem` on the command line, I see the following lines added to `~/.cache/gdm/session.log`:

```
Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x280000b (Videos)
Window manager warning: meta_window_activate called by a pager with a 0 timestamp; the pager needs to be fixed.
```

and the following lines on the terminal:

```
(totem:3232): Grilo-WARNING **: [registry] grl-registry.c:434: Could not open plugins' info directory '/usr/lib/grilo-0.2': Error opening directory '/usr/lib/grilo-0.2': No such file or directory
(totem:3232): Totem-WARNING **: Failed to load grilo plugins: All configured plugin paths are invalid. Failed to load plugins.
```

The grilo warnings I've seen before this problem started; I don't have it installed.

Comment: @don_crissti, yes, I'm using the default icon theme.  I've tried changing icon themes with `gnome-tweak-tool`, but all that does is give me a different broken icon for all controls.

Comment: I tried updating the icon cache.  I got no errors, but it didn't make any difference.  Neither did rebooting.

Comment: @don_crissti, that did it!  (Well, I only reinstalled `librsvg` and ran `gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache`; I didn't use `-Rdd`).  But the controls are back.  Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of behavior is usually caused by icon & pixbuf loaders problems.

Re-installing **`librsvg`** and running (as root):

```
gtk-update-icon-cache -f /usr/share/icons/gnome

gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache
```

should, in most cases, fix it.